# How to check that current time is not larger than midnight?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, console-application

I have a method that checks if the current time is larger tha 00(midnight).
if i get back true then i send an email, if not then I don't send it. Last night I got 40 emails which should not have been sent.

I tried these two attempts:

```
    TimeSpan max = new TimeSpan(00, 0, 0);
    TimeSpan now = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay;

    if (now > max)
        return false;

    return true;
```

And this:

```
TimeSpan max = new TimeSpan(24, 0, 0);
TimeSpan now = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay;
if (now> max)
    return false;

return true;
```

In the first case I get that now is alway larger than max and in the second i get that now is always less than max.

i want my method to return true if the time is between
07-24

Other case i want to return false.

how do i do this?

Comment: Forget about the whole "after midnight" thing (what does that even _mean_ - every time is after midnight), and instead rework it to your actual requirement: _"return true if the time is between 07-24"_ Just check if the current hour is in that range.

Comment: Can you define "larger than midnight"?  With respect to what?

Comment: Are you thinking about feeding a mogwai?

Comment: That could be a bit consufing sorry. Simply put I want to return true between 07-24. anything else i want to return false. In otherwords i dont want any emails being sent in the middle of the night.

Comment: @Default, gremlin m8, most definitely a gremlin:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want between the 7 and 24 hour, just check the current hour, ignore the rest of the date and time bits

see: https://dotnetfiddle.net/1LCvRP

```
public bool IsHourInRange() 
{
    var currentHour = DateTime.Now.Hour;
    return currentHour >= 7;
}
```

Comment: But...it's still correct. At 7am the `.Hour` will be 7. At 12:15am, the hour will be zero.

Comment: Am I right in assuming that lets say at 12:01 the hour will be zero aswell?

Comment: You mean a minute after midnight? yes